# Strange behaviour of m.erase() function in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, ordered-map

```cpp
int main(){
    map<int, int> m;
    m.insert({1,2});
    m.insert({2,3});
    m.insert({5,10});
    m.erase(m.find(3));
    for(auto &x: m){
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<nl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
5 10
```

As far as I know `m.find(3)` returns iterator to the `m.end()` if key is not found. Then why pair {2,3} is deleted?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)? "_The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used as a value for `pos`._" You violated the contract - hence undefined behavior is invoked.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius _Did you read the documentation for `std::vector::erase`?_ Even more interesting could be [std::map::erase()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)... ;-)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius please do not post answer as a comment

Comment: Your assumption that `erase()` accepts end iterator and produce a noop is invalid. See the answer.

Comment: @Slava I, personally, don't consider "RTFM-like" answers as being worthy of being considered answers, since the first place you should look, when using some API, and getting strange behavior is the documentation, and asking such questions shouldn't be encouraged (as, clearly, no research has been done, while doing the research is a precondition on asking questions in SO). But that's, maybe, just me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pair is deleted because you violated a pre-condition of [`std::map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

> ```
> iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
> iterator erase( iterator pos );
> ```
>
> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end()
> iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used
> as a value for pos.

Violating a pre-condition of a standard library function has undefined behavior. So deleting a seemingly random element is totally in line with that.